# Manage .net shared libraries in a small size company (50+ developers)

Tags: .net, gac

In my company we are 50+ developers. There are around 9 projects that share a lot of common libraries (20+) Tis process is becoming more and more complex every day. The main problems are:

1. how to keep track of what was changed in each version of the library
2. where to store those assemblies. Now we use a shared drive and we have a convention: /lib/version/*.dll
3. how to automatically embed correct libraries at build time. We currently use a .targets file in visual studio that we manually update.

How do you manage this aspect in your company?

Comment: Err... SVN? Or any other major version control system should do the trick

Comment: 50+ developer is no small shop ! 10 is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't done this, you might try packaging up your libraries as Nuget packages, and run a internal Nuget server to serve them up.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

We're starting to do a similar thing with our Ruby libraries that we need to share across teams - package them up as gems and serve them from an internal gem server.

Comment: nice idea ... I was thinking of developing a custom solution for this ... but Nuget does a very good job

Answer (score 0):

I run free-ware version of TeamCity that can automatically build project (some MSBuild customization required) then output file published in TeamCity with downloaded-able link for example: http://10.0.0.194:8111/guestAuth/repository/download/bt3/.lastSuccessful/Project.dll. In my project I overwrite 'BeforeBuild' section in MSBuild and download the Project.dll file with this link - this I make sure that:

- I'm using latest version of Project.dll (it always saved in the same http link)
- The dll (or anything) I download was passed some tests (depends on TeamCity configuration)
- I work independently from other programmer because I don't have manually copy/paste or use share drive
- It accessible from any IDE/program/whatever that can access site and download file (Java, C++, Python, etc..)
- etc, etc, etc...